# python | как скопировать все содержимое папки КРОМЕ чего-нибудь

Tags: python

есть `C:\papka`, в ней хранятся `123.py`, `123.txt`, `test1` и `test2` (test'ы это папки со своим содержимым)

вопрос такой: как мне скопировать только, скажем, `123.txt` и `test2`, проигнорировав `123.py` и `test1`?

ps копировать надо в какую то другую папку, например в `D:/qwerty/qwerty`,
код:

```
papkaPath = os.path.abspath("C:/papka")
shutil.copytree(papkaPath, dist)' # функция копирования
```

Comment: Вы покажите, что вы уже сделали. Например, как прочитали содержимое вашего каталога `c:\papka`.

Comment: @strawdog показал

Comment: копировать файлы по одному и смотреть каждому на имя,

Answer (score 0):

Использовать именованый параметр `ignore` в сочетании с собственной функцией, либо с функцией `ignore_patterns`

```
from shutil import copytree, ignore_patterns

copytree(source, destination, ignore=ignore_patterns('*.pyc', 'dir/folder/file.ext'))
```

Либо пойти по более примитивному пути,- копировать во временную папку, удалять исключения, копировать в целевую папку, но при больших размерах данный вариант не применим.